# What does this phrase mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage, phrase-meaning

> You must not lament in conversation with your savior over the trifles of an average boy.

what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***To lament*** means; *mourn aloud, wail, express sorrow, grieve for; bewail, bemoan,
 regret*

***Trifle*** in this context means; *matter or object of small value or of little importance*

In the sentence

> You must not lament in conversation with your savior over the trifles
>   of an average boy.

your pen-pal's admonishment might be interpreted in two ways.

- **1.** The pen pal is saying not to waste your *savior's* time over petty, insignificant details. The aches and pains of a romantic relationship with an ordinary boy are unimportant and trivial compared to the *magnitude* of events, concerns and innumerable requests he has to deal with on a day to day basis. The message implied is that if you are to "pray" or beseech his guidance then do so for things which are more important. Your pen pal does not say what these things are or may be.
- **2.** The meaning is similar to the one posted by @Ace Frahm, that your grievances over the problems of a boy may be experiencing, an average boy at that, is of little importance to your *saviour*. The word, "average", in this context I would read very negatively. In other words this  person, according to your pen pal, is  mediocre and ordinary and his problems are of little value and consequence.

Finally, it is worth pointing out that in both cases it has been your pen pal who has classified these problems as being trivial and insignificant. Whether she or he is correct in making these rather arrogant claims is a separate issue but one you might do well to reflect on.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing any of the context about who the "savior" is, or what the trifles are, or who the boy is [you|someone you know|your pen pal], or whether he is mutually understood as average or not,

this sentence seems to mean that:

you should not complain or express sorrow to [your savior|allah|god|jesus|superman] about this boy's problems.

Possibly because the boy is average & thus unimportant, or because the boy's problem's are no different than any other person's problems, or maybe your pen pal thinks you have more important things to talk about to [your savior|krishna|budha|jesus|aquaman].  Or maybe that you shouldn't let this boy's problems become your problems.

In any case, it sounds like bad advice to me, as gods aren't real, so you'd be wasting time better spent taking real action.  And even if they were, we should still have some concern for our fellow man.